# How to view elements in design view using a scrollviewer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Visual Studio WP 2010. 
I'm using scrollviewer for text and images on a page, but in design view in VS I can only view the first part of the page which makes placing text and images difficult.  I can take a guess and then run the app in the emulator, scroll down to see how far off I am, then go back in design view and try to set margins, height, etc appropriately. Is there another easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: During creation set the ScrollViewer's [VerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: That doesn't change anything as far as allowing me to view the text and images that go below the bottom extent of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer elsewhere.  In the top section of your xaml find d:DesignHeight="696" and change the 696 to something like 2000, etc.  This will extent the viewing area.  Anytime you reload or run the application it will default back, but it's easy to reset.